# How can I take a SQL file and have it import into Rails Active Record base connection?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I know how to execute raw SQL and I've found this command from other SO answers, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("Dump20171031.sql"))` but I have no idea where I need to put this/what to do with it. I'm doing a class project and my partner has added some test data to a database and we're simply trying to connect the database, a `.sql` file, with the Rails backend

Comment: import the sql file filled with data into your mysql server from terminal.

Comment: Why don't you use `pqsl` or `pg_restore` command for importing. Something like `psql db_name < path_to_your_file/Dump20171031.sql` should work

Answer (score 1):

You can put that line into rails console and it should work.
Go to your rails project and type `rails console` to get into the console.